# I want to read a pdf file and send it to another server and make it read again

Tags: php, pdf-generation, file-get-contents

What i want to do here is i want to read a pdf file from SERVER 2 and send content to SERVER 1 and then show that pdf file on SERVER 2 in an iFrame.

So for example

SERVER 1 sends a request with file ID or name to SERVER 2. Then SERVER 2 file_get_content pdf file and return the content to SERVER 1 and then SERVER 1 shows the content as a PDF, but the problem i am facing here is SERVER 1 has some kind of unreadable content which i cant convert into PDF. Any idea how i can show it as the original pdf ??

ok so here is my code may be this gives you more deeper view

i am sending request to SERVER 2 here:

```
    $reqfile    = "http://REMOTESERVER/docmgt/index.php";  
    $sdurl = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,"filename=".$sdurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $reqfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);     

    echo $rec_Data;

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

Below is the index.php file code:

```
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];   
    if($filename =='')
    echo "No file is selectedd";
    else{  
    $pdffile = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo $pdffile;
    }
```

And the output i am geeting as $rec_Data is :

```
    ----- some garbage with diamond shape symbols ----
```

now i think its the pdf content i just need to rebuild it to show it into iframe or object.

Comment: It's probably going to be difficult to help you without seeing the code you're using.

Comment: we are not going to do your project

Comment: PDF consists of bytes. You want to get those bytes from Server 2 and pass them on through Server 1. Reading your question it sounds as Server 1 corrupts the bytes (makes them unreadable). Why is this a question tagged as 'pdf-generation', you're not generating PDF anywhere in the process, are you? You're just passing bytes from one server to another... Why is PDF relevant in your question? Please use Occam's razor to simplify your question.